# When a page switches programmatically in Ionic Framework it breaks that page?

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

In my Ionic Framework v3 app I a programmatically sending data to another page and when I try to get back to that page immediately it shows a broken version of the home page.

The page before switching:

[image: Before Switch]

After Switching (when I try to return to that page):

[image: After switching]

The done button is what switches the page with this code:

```
done() {
    this.navCtrl.push(HomePage, {
        drinkOption: drinkOption,
        drinkValue: amountOfDrink
    });

    this.navCtrl.parent.select(0);
}
```

Then the home page receives it with this code:

```
if (navParams.get('drinkOption') && navParams.get('drinkValue')) {
    this.drinkOption = navParams.get('drinkOption');
    this.amountOfDrink = navParams.get('drinkValue');

    saveDrink(this.drinkOption, this.amountOfDrink);
}
```

Ionic Info:

```
cli packages: (/Users/user/.config/yarn/global/node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0 
Gulp CLI              : CLI version 3.9.1 Local version 3.9.1

local packages:

@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9
Cordova Platforms  : ios 4.5.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.1-201711081842

System:

ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
ios-sim    : 6.1.2 
Node       : v8.9.4
npm        : 5.6.0 
OS         : macOS High Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 9.3 Build version 9E145 

Environment Variables:

ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

backend : pro
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: is this necessary? `this.navCtrl.parent.select(0);
`

Comment: @Yerkon Yes or else the nav bar does not update.